# CommentThreads.list 403

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm getting:

> {
> "error": {
> "code": 403,
> "message": "The video identified by the \u003ccode\u003e\u003ca href="/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list#videoId"\u003evideoId\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/code\u003e parameter has disabled comments.",
> "errors": [
> {
> "message": "The video identified by the \u003ccode\u003e\u003ca href="/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list#videoId"\u003evideoId\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/code\u003e parameter has disabled comments.",
> "domain": "youtube.commentThread",
> "reason": "commentsDisabled",
> "location": "videoId",
> "locationType": "parameter"
> }
> ]
> }
> }

for

```
GET https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=snippet,replies&allThreadsRelatedToChannelId=UC14YzmOgfiBEvEEeCDAtfjg
```

I could not identify any video on that channel with comment-disabled.
Moreover, I do try similar api call on channels that I know that have some videos with comment-disabled - and this API works perfectly (UCb0igM0fY85iaKarWkcLOAQ) with no errors.

Please advise - what's the logic regarding this error..
Thanks

Comment: I used a lot YouTube Data API v3 for retrieving comments and I don't what secret parameters some channels have but they aren't clear. I stopped looking for logic here. Is there a problem for you to just list all videos of the given channel and retrieving them by providing the `videoId` and not the `channelId` to [CommentThreads: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list) ?

Comment: this may help https://stackoverflow.com/q/70013112/1841839 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/71969897/1841839

Comment: well i can - but this is far from ideal as i would like to get in one call all the engagements that happened since i last call the api ( as the comments comed in desc chronological order ) 
Checking all the videos - of a channel - to find new comments - will also have a quota impact.